# How to decode the video file to upload to server?

Tags: android, video, file-upload, ftp

I am trying to upload media files to server from phone. I have uploaded the image file in server from phone.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, stream); //compress to which format you want.
        byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
        image_str = Base64.encodeBytes(byte_arr);
```

Now am trying to upload video file, for image we have bitmap and bitmapfactory to upload. But any idea for image. Please reply if you have any idea to decode the video file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just go through http://coderzheaven.com/2011/08/uploading-audio-video-or-image-files-from-android-to-server/

If you want to upload video to server then see **doFileUpload()** method from the above url.